# Hiding Columns by matching a cell entry to the respective row data of the columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter out columns which do not contain the letter I enter in a cell which corresponds to the row.

I have constructed a matrix of Blanks, K's and E's 
On the top there is names
on the left there are categories

for each name and category there is an assigned K, E or Blank
I want to enter either K or E next to each category (ideally using a drop down menu) and that will filter out every name which does not have the letter I entered in respect to this particular category.

One person may have a K, E or Blank but not a combination of them within a particular catagory.

I have searched everywhere for how to do this but I'm stumped. I'm not particularly proficient in VBA or Excel but I feel like this should be a simple problem which is why it's frustrating

I'm tryin to create something like this:

> If
>
> the value in cell(x,n) [column, row] = "K" or "E"  Then  for the
>
> range to right of column x
>
> hide every column which does not contain an "E" or "K" in row n

or you could say only show columns which contain an E or K in row n

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have tried to create a data validation drop down menu for each cell in a column using vba and a combination of online tutorials and then linking each cell to the data in its corresponding row.

however using the methods i saw, I would need an individual piece of code for each row... and i have over 100 rows

Comment: you need to loop the columns and do something like countif, so `columns(x).entirecolumn.hidden= countif(column(x).offset(0,x),value)>0`  where value is what you are looking for, and x is a loop for the columns

Comment: @Desktop, it's kinda hard for me to fully understand your problem. Maybe you could add a screenshot or try to visualize the structure of your data.

Comment: I think I can try to explain better.

If the value in cell(x,n) [column, row] = "K" or "E"

Then

for the range to right of **column x**

hide every column which does not contain an "E" or "K" in **row n**